# Flask SocketIO app hosted on Heroku not using @socketio.on events?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, socket.io, flask-socketio

As you can see in the logs posted below, the data sent from the "frontend" is coming through. But the only indication that it's coming through is from the `SocketIO`'s logging options, not from the code I wrote.

Everything works great when *hosted locally*. But when I host it on Heroku, it doesn't work the same way. I'm not getting any errors or crashes or anything like that, but the only indication I'm seeing of successful communication is from the SocketIO's logging (`engine_iologger=True` and `logger=True`). The actual events and functions I defined aren't ever being used, it seems like.

**my_app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=".")
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "fake key man"
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", engineio_logger=True, logger=True)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

    
@socketio.on("message")
def on_message(message):
    print(f"message: {message}")
    send("Hey, from the server")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 my_app:app
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    button {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello this is the index</h1>
  <button>Button!</button>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.4.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-nYuHvSAhY5lFZ4ixSViOwsEKFvlxHMU2NHts1ILuJgOS6ptUmAGt/0i5czIgMOahKZ6JN84YFDA+mCdky7dD8A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="static/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function buttonClicked(){
  console.log("sending message");
  socket.send("Hello, from the client");
}


document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);
// const socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:5000");
const socket = io.connect("http://total-confusion.herokuapp.com/socket.io");

socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("connected!");
})

socket.on("message", data => {
  console.log(`data: ${data}`);
})
```

**Heroku logs**

```
2021-12-05T19:52:46.020757+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 my_app:app`
2021-12-05T19:52:47.724970+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-05T19:52:47.501740+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-05 19:52:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-12-05T19:52:47.502072+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-05 19:52:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:29329 (4)
2021-12-05T19:52:47.502115+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-05 19:52:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker
2021-12-05T19:52:47.505637+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-05 19:52:47 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-12-05T19:52:48.278493+00:00 app[web.1]: Server initialized for gevent.
2021-12-05T19:52:50.660919+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=7dk50RlRE2-P4ERfAAAC" host=total-confusion.herokuapp.com request_id=4115671c-13e5-4d0a-8143-2bb424683d48 fwd="174.70.52.92" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=314509ms status=101 bytes=129 protocol=http
2021-12-05T19:52:50.761966+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=total-confusion.herokuapp.com request_id=016c2145-a9e6-4144-8dde-24d49327d0db fwd="174.70.52.92" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=808 protocol=http
2021-12-05T19:52:51.224044+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/script.js" host=total-confusion.herokuapp.com request_id=d4c6c836-ec0e-41d3-9ade-92c8da94509d fwd="174.70.52.92" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=691 protocol=http
2021-12-05T19:52:51.218524+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-05 19:52:51 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-12-05T19:52:51.363409+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-05 19:52:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-12-05T19:52:51.512198+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-12-05T19:52:51.455324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NsCA1iy&sid=NwMwXg3pkqnB5t3UAAAA" host=total-confusion.herokuapp.com request_id=74a5cc6d-fa13-49c4-a835-53b8408579b3 fwd="174.70.52.92" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=200 protocol=http
2021-12-05T19:52:51.392948+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NsCA1i3" host=total-confusion.herokuapp.com request_id=16381dc8-17dd-448d-8967-3704ab523483 fwd="174.70.52.92" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=254 protocol=http
2021-12-05T19:52:51.451450+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NsCA1iw&sid=NwMwXg3pkqnB5t3UAAAA" host=total-confusion.herokuapp.com request_id=9a85832d-c36f-459c-aae9-c6a344555e87 fwd="174.70.52.92" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=210 protocol=http
2021-12-05T19:52:51.393695+00:00 app[web.1]: NwMwXg3pkqnB5t3UAAAA: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': 'NwMwXg3pkqnB5t3UAAAA', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
2021-12-05T19:52:51.452253+00:00 app[web.1]: NwMwXg3pkqnB5t3UAAAA: Received packet MESSAGE data 0/socket.io,
2021-12-05T19:52:51.452457+00:00 app[web.1]: NwMwXg3pkqnB5t3UAAAA: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0/socket.io,{"sid":"ax17karHdBzwH5yzAAAB"}
2021-12-05T19:52:51.502132+00:00 app[web.1]: NwMwXg3pkqnB5t3UAAAA: Received request to upgrade to websocket
2021-12-05T19:52:51.862767+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NsCA1pM&sid=NwMwXg3pkqnB5t3UAAAA" host=total-confusion.herokuapp.com request_id=d640c10c-848b-41d0-900d-e2719472d9ed fwd="174.70.52.92" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=157 protocol=http
2021-12-05T19:52:51.920149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NsCA1qC&sid=NwMwXg3pkqnB5t3UAAAA" host=total-confusion.herokuapp.com request_id=4cb0eb2d-564e-424c-ab66-9d8409f558d7 fwd="174.70.52.92" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=157 protocol=http
2021-12-05T19:52:51.965935+00:00 app[web.1]: NwMwXg3pkqnB5t3UAAAA: Upgrade to websocket successful
2021-12-05T19:52:52.788905+00:00 app[web.1]: NwMwXg3pkqnB5t3UAAAA: Received packet MESSAGE data 2/socket.io,["message","Hello, from the client"]
2021-12-05T19:52:52.789077+00:00 app[web.1]: received event "message" from ax17karHdBzwH5yzAAAB [/socket.io]
```

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have solved my own problem minutes after posting this. If I remove the `/socket.io` bit from the Heroku URL, then it fixes the issue. I confirmed this by *adding* `/socket.io` to the end of the local URL, and the same behavior occurs. Sweet!

If anyone knows *why* this is, though, please let me know! I'm not sure why I ever used `/socket.io`, I think it is just one of those changes that came about when trying to fix a different problem and it stayed, so I don't have any understanding of what that does.

Comment: The `/socket.io` endpoint does not need to be specified, it is added automatically by the Socket.IO client.